# Code generator for dart

Tags: dart, generated-code

I need to do mapper between dart and JS object. I don't like to write  "unncessary' code  so I would like DartEditor wrote it for me :)

What i would like  to write:

```dart
DartInvoice extends jsw.TypedProxy {
     @Parser(attributName="invoice")
     String number;
     @Parser(attributName=amount)
     Number sum;
}
```

What i would like to achieve:

```dart
DartInvoice extends jsw.TypedProxy {
     set number(String number) => toJs.set('invoice' : number);
     String number => toJs.get(invoice);
     set sum(Number sum) => toJs.set('amount' : sum);
     Number get sum => toJs.get(amount);
}
```

The question is :) how dart or dart editor can help me?  Tell me what i should read. :)

Comment: [Custom build scripts](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/build.html) might be a good place to start for things like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started the [js_wrapping_generator](https://github.com/a14n/dart-js-wrapping-generator) project to do something like that but its not quite ready for prime time. I used the [analyzer](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/analyzer) package to parse dart files an generate other files.

You can have a look at [dart_generator.dart](https://github.com/a14n/dart-js-wrapping-generator/blob/master/lib/dart_generator.dart) to have a sample.

The current version is based on a simple AST and I'm working on a new version based on a resolved AST to simplify templating even more.

Comment: GREAT This is what i wanted to do :))
It would be great to have ability to change attribute name. For example when JS object has name that isn't appropriate for me. That's why I wanted to use annotations.

THIS GONNA BE GREAT library for anyone who is porting js libraries to dart.

Please, consider ability to change attribute / class names between JS and Dart object.

Comment: Please [file an issue](https://github.com/a14n/dart-js-wrapping-generator/issues/new) to track this.